# Unable to understand the output

Tags: java, multithreading

As per my understanding if i have used a synchronized keyword then only one thread can enter and once it leaves then only other thread.But why my below code is printing sometimes First 2
Second 2

```
package com.vikash.GeeksForGeeks;

public class Test implements Runnable{

    private  static  int count;

    public  synchronized  void  incrementCount()
    {
        count++;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+count);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Thread t1=new Thread(new Test());
        Thread t2=new Thread(new Test());
        t1.start();t1.setName("First");
        t2.start();t2.setName("Second");
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.println("Count Value="+count);

    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        incrementCount();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating two separate instances of `Test`, and your `incrementCount` method is an *instance* method despite it incrementing a *static* variable.

Each of your threads operates on a different instance of `Test`, so they won't block each other, and you run into the normal race conditions.

If you make `incrementCount` a static method, then both threads will be trying to acquire the monitor for `Test.class`, and it should work in those terms. (Although there's no guarantee that the `main` thread will read the most-recently-written value of `count`...)

Alternatively, create *one* instance of `Test`, and pass that to both `Thread` constructors, at which point they'll both be trying to acquire the monitor for the same instance of `Test`. The crucial point is that if the two threads are acquiring different monitors, they'll both be able to do it without waiting for the other...